# Unexpected "@" in program

Tags: objective-c, symbols

Ok so basically I am trying to link a label to a block of code in  XCode 4.6.2. I linked it using the designer but regardless of where I put it, it gives me this error message. I am new to xcode and feel like this should be a simple fix. thanks for the feed back/

```
(void)updateLabel {
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Timer;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
        [dateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c", [components month], 'M', [components day], 'D', [components hour], 'H', [components minute], 'M', [components second], 'S']];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        destinationDate = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1383652800] retain];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



}
```

Comment: What error message????

Comment: (But an `@property` statement is not allowed inside a method definition, and, in fact, shouldn't even be in the .m file.)

Comment: (And an instance/property name should begin with a lower-case letter.)

Comment: @HotLicks More correctly, an `@property` must be declared in an `@interface`. This could be a public interface in a .h or a private interface (class extension) in a .m.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that an `@property` can only appear inside an `@interface`. This can be in a .h file or in a class extension in the .m file. But it most certainly can't be put inside a method implementation.

Given that your property is also an `IBOutlet`, it should be in the .h file.

Side Note:

The way you create the label's text is odd. At a minimum, do this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dM %dD %dH %dM %dS", [components month], [components day], [components hour], [components minute], [components second]];
```

Better yet, use an `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"M'M' d'D' H'H' m'M' s'S'"];
dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: `Given that your property is also an IBOutlet, it should be in the .h file`: I always wanted to ask whether to put `IBOutlets` in the `.h` or `.m` file. Is there any reason for that? If I don't need them anywhere else I always put them in the `.m`. Is that bad style or even wrong?

Comment: @HAS Your .h provides the public interface to your class. If you treat Interface Builder as another client of your class, then adding `IBOutlet` to the .h makes the most sense. There is no need to use `IBOutlet` in the .m file at all since there is no need for IB to know anything about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

the @property declaration doesn't belong in your function. 
You should always place "@" declarations BEFORE the function.